# Bash script to determine a distro, update, upgrade and install the apps I use

Tags: beginner, bash, linux, installer

This is my first bash script. I am trying to learn scripting and needed an idea. This is the first idea I came up with. When I used to distro hop I had to reinstall everything. This helped me out once I got the first part working. Then I wanted to add if then else for more than just Debian distros.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script Name : app_install.sh
#Author inflatus
#Created 4 Sept 2015
#Version 0.4

#Description
 #This script will determine the distributon of Linux and use the      appropriate package manager to install my core apps

current_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
close_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID_LIKE=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`

echo "$current_distro"
echo "$close_distro"

if [ "$close_distro" = "debian" ]; then

  #Debian
  #Install my apps on a fresh install of a Debian based Linux

  echo "This script will install your apps after a fresh install"

  apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
  apt-get install htop traceroute whois gparted curl nmap openvpn rsync iptraf openssh-client git gimp hexchat unison -y

  #Adding repositories

  echo "Adding the repos"

  add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:mumble/release -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-1 -y
  add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable -y

  apt-get update
  apt-get install telegram mumble handbrake simplescreenrecorder remmina remmina-plugin-rdp libfreerdp-plugins-standard libreoffice wireshark -y
  apt-get dist-upgrade -y

  #Time to clean

  echo "Alright, cleaning now."

  apt-get autoclean

  #Finished install

  echo "Finished."

elif [ "$close_distro" != "debian" ]; then

  #Fedora
  #Install my apps on a fresh install of a Fedora based Linux

  echo "This script will install your apps after a fresh install"

  dnf check-update -y
  dnf update -y
  dnf install htop traceroute jwhois gparted curl nmap openvpn rsync iptraf openssh-clients git gimp mumble remmina-plugins-rdp wireshark hexchat -y
  dnf clean all

  #Time to clean

  echo "Alright, cleaning now."
  dnf clean all

  #Finished install

   echo "Finished."

 else

   echo "This is not for you."
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simplifying `if-elif-else`

The `else` statement here is *dead code*, it can never happen:

> ```
> if [ "$close_distro" = "debian" ]; then
>   # commands to run if debian
> elif [ "$close_distro" != "debian" ]; then
>   # commands to run if NOT debian
> else
>    echo "This is not for you."
> fi
> ```

The conditions can be simplified to this:

```
if [ "$close_distro" = debian ]; then
  # commands to run if debian
else
  # commands to run if NOT debian
fi
```

I also dropped the unnecessary double-quoting around the literal string `debian`.

#### Prefer `$(...)` over `` `...` ``

When using sub-shells, instead the obsolete `` `...` ``,
always use the modern syntax `$(...)`.

#### Simplify a chain of commands with `awk` when possible

In each of these commands, there are 3 processes executed: `cat`, `grep` and another `grep`:

> ```
> current_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
> close_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID_LIKE=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
> ```

You can make that more efficient by rewriting each using a single `awk`:

```
current_distro=$(awk -F= '$1 == "ID" { print $2 }' /etc/*-release)
close_distro=$(awk -F= '$1 == "ID_LIKE" { print $2 }' /etc/*-release)
```